# Plot Elements from List of Lists in Multiple Colors

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to plot the elements from a list of lists, specifically coloring each point according the class to which it belongs, using the outer list index as a x value and the value of each element of the inner list as a y value.  An example list, with 2 sublists:

```
sample.list <- list(list("A"=0,"B"=0.14285, "C"=0.75), list("A"=0.138,"B"=0,"C"=0.1))
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
[1] 0

[[1]]$B
[1] 0.14285

[[1]]$C
[1] 0.75

[[2]]
[[2]]$A
[1] 0.138

[[2]]$B
[1] 0

[[2]]$C
[1] 0.1
```

My desired output would plot the first sublist at the points

`(1, 0), (1, 0.14285), (1, 0.5)`

(i.e. the sublist elements form a vertical line along `x=1`) and the second sublist would be similarly plotted.  Additionally, each sublist element would have a different color - `A` could be red, `B` green etc. Just to clarify, I am trying to do this all on one graph.  Moreover, the number of list elements could change from depending on the dataset.  Any pointers as to how to tackle this issue are very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(ldply(sample.list, data.frame))
df2 <- ddply(df, .(variable), function(x) { x$index <- 1:nrow(x); x})
ggplot(df2, aes(index, value, color = variable)) + 
geom_point(size=3) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1:max(df2$index)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost it!  However, what I am trying to do is take each sublist as a set of y values whose x values are the outer list index.  So in your plot, there would be x coordinates, each of which would have 3 points.

Comment: realized my mistake after posting. How's this version?

Comment: That's perfect.  I am constantly amazed at how much R there is to learn.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base solution for those non-ggplot-ers:

```
plot(1:length(sample.list),ylim=c(0,max(unlist(sample.list))),xaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
axis(1,at=1:length(sample.list),labels=1:length(sample.list))

invisible(
  sapply(
      1:length(sample.list),
      function(x) {
        tmp2plot <- sample.list[[x]]
        points(rep(x,length(tmp2plot)),unlist(tmp2plot),col=1:length(tmp2plot),pch=19)
      }
  )
)

title(xlab="Index",ylab="Value")
```

Result:

[image]