# Plotting elements of each list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, plot, graphics

Assume I have a list of lists as bellow. Note that they don't have indices (so [Plot Elements from List of Lists in Multiple Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899376/plot-elements-from-list-of-lists-in-multiple-colors) doesn't work). I want to plot each element of the list of lists in different color, in a single plot; the first element in all the list of lists be plotted in red, the second in blue and so on. The plot would have three x-axis values (each corresponding to one list) and 14 lines in it. I want this to be a line plot rather than points. This is just a sample of my data and I have way more elements in each list and the list is much longer so I'd appreciate it if you could provide an automatic scheme for coloring as well.

Here's my sample data:

```
dput(eig_inter_list)
list(structure(c(0.35292487525346, 0.60691801065057, 1, 0.580488938067023, 
0.309868800437186, 0.803624552294329, 0.859614844376857, 0.945322316985286, 
0.66382386229292, 0.582923451391743, 0.700743501629888, 0.54057650370494, 
0.618018253507612, 0.827733889516536), .Dim = c(14L, 1L)), structure(c(0.277569256062068, 
0.349586859887733, 0.501330486808658, 0.512673497480961, 0.415383940065017, 
0.580991046711227, 0.662789950341437, 0.715112711298967, 0.527336235410471, 
0.307662169519342, 1, 0.569881462583403, 0.770921042348471, 0.601883082654194
), .Dim = c(14L, 1L)), structure(c(0.497890982517205, 0.408808327528174, 
0.458163926773143, 0.647830131597746, 0.497917404040468, 0.884088378425421, 
0.597378982413682, 1, 0.731715482131051, 0.937716641217791, 0.81980698262881, 
0.761533227649694, 0.791174439173143, 0.53885600731611), .Dim = c(14L, 
1L)))
```

Comment: Do you want to plot all lists in a single plot or each one in a separate plot?

Comment: In a single plot, I've added it in the question, thanks. @YacineHajji

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `str`ucture, it is just a `list` of `matrix`ces with a single column.  An option is to loop over the `list` with `Map` along with a vector/list of corresponding `col`ors to plot.  Specify the `par` before plotting to have it in a single page

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
Map(function(x, col) plot(x, type = 'l', color = col), 
     eig_inter_list, c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

-output

[image]

---

If we want to plot in a single plot, `cbind` the `matrix`es in to a single matrix with 3 columns and use `matplot`

```
matplot(do.call(cbind, eig_inter_list), type = "l", 
      col = c('red', 'blue', 'green'), lty = 1, ylab = "value")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I added a description for the plot. I want all of them to be in one plot and in x-axis we would have three points, each corresponding to a list.

Comment: lines, I meant those three points on x-axis would be for each value in each list. x-axis should be the index of the list and y-axis the value in the lists.

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: Nice plots. Had no idea that you also plot!